# Collision detection only works when a key is being pressed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
        void snake_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            e.IsInputKey = true;

            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                up_ispressed = true;
                down_ispressed = false;
                left_ispressed = false;
                right_ispressed = false;

                snake.Top = snake.Top + i;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                up_ispressed = false;
                down_ispressed = true;
                left_ispressed = false;
                right_ispressed = false;

                snake.Top = snake.Top + j;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                up_ispressed = false;
                down_ispressed = false;
                left_ispressed = true;
                right_ispressed = false;

                snake.Left = snake.Left + i;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                up_ispressed = false;
                down_ispressed = false;
                left_ispressed = false;
                right_ispressed = true;

                snake.Left = snake.Left + j;
            } 
            
            //if 'snake' touches the 'apple', change its size, speed and give the player 100 points
            if (snake.Bounds.IntersectsWith(apple.Bounds))
            {
                GenerateApple();              
                points = points + 100;
                i = i + -1;
                j = j + 1;
                k = k + 10;
                snake.Size = new Size(k,k);
                this.Text = "Score: " + points;
            }
        }
```

Here is my code. As you can see, I detect the collision between 'snake' and 'apple' using Bounds.IntersectsWith() but the collision is only detected when a key is being pressed. How can I solve this issue?

*Sorry for the bad code. I am a begginer.*

Comment: Where is the code of the game loop moving the snake?

Comment: The question is what the rest of the code does. Based on "Snake" I assume that the part where the snake moves is working somewhere else (in another function). You will need to move the `if` for the collision check to the movement function.

Comment: @PeterBons I used a timer for that but stackoverflow didn't let me put too much code

Comment: @MarkusDeibel thank you so much. I put the colision control in the timer too.